# Simple Finite sum inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality

I really run out of the ideas proving this inequality: Suppose for $1\leq k\leq n$, we know $$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \geq 0$$ and $z_1\geq z_2 \geq \cdots \geq z_n \geq0$, how do we show $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_iz_i \geq 0$$.

I tried a few approaches but none of them work: I think the key to prove it is to exploit the monotonicity of $z_i$. For example, we can write $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_iz_i=(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)z_n+ (z_1-z_n)a_1+(z_2-z_n)a_2+\cdots+ (z_{n-1}-z_n)a_{n-1}$$
Clearly on the right, the first term is larger than $0$, each coefficient of $a_i$'s is larger than $0$, but there is no guarantee of $a_i's$. My another thought is that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iz_i$ looks like an inner product and we might need Cauchy-Schwarz inequality here. But the direction of inequality is not right. Any thought/hint on how to prove the statement is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [Abel's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_inequality). Let us denote by $A_k = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$, then we can write:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i z_i = z_nA_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i(z_{i+1}-z_i) = z_nA_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i(z_{i}-z_{i+1}) \geq0$$

This is true, because $A_i \geq 0$ and $z_{i}-z_{i+1} \geq 0$.

Comment: I've never heard of the Abel's transform before. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: It is also called *summation by parts*.

Comment: @DMS no problem, if you find it useful, consider marking as correct;>